# Representing tamil unicode in netbeans 7.1

Tags: java, netbeans, tamil

How to represent Tamil unicodes in netbeans 7.1? I have installed `Azhagi` to use Tamil unicode.

I am able to type Tamil in any text files. But where can I do it in netbeans 7.1? The characters are rendering as boxes.

Comment: Check this https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199976

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this as per that link

Instead of font Latha you need to use yours Azhagi

## The solution in Windows JRE is

Copy JRE_HOME/lib/fontconfig.properties.src to JRE_HOME/lib/fontconfig.properties. and edit this file as the following diff.

### Diff on JRE 1.7.0 u4 32 bit

```
D:\dev\jdk1.7.0_04_32bit\jre\lib> diff -bc fontconfig.properties.src fontconfig.properties
*** fontconfig.properties.src   Mon Jun 11 13:42:13 2012
--- fontconfig.properties       Mon Jun 11 15:09:42 2012
***************
*** 42,47 ****
--- 42,48 ----
  allfonts.symbol=Symbol
  allfonts.thai=Lucida Sans Regular
  allfonts.georgian=Sylfaen
+ allfonts.tamil=Latha

  serif.plain.alphabetic=Times New Roman
  serif.plain.chinese-ms950=MingLiU
***************
*** 185,191 ****

  # Search Sequences

! sequence.allfonts=alphabetic/default,dingbats,symbol

  sequence.serif.GBK=alphabetic,chinese-ms936,dingbats,symbol,chinese-ms936-extb
  sequence.sansserif.GBK=alphabetic,chinese-ms936,dingbats,symbol,chinese-ms936-extb
--- 186,192 ----

  # Search Sequences

! sequence.allfonts=alphabetic/default,dingbats,symbol,tamil

  sequence.serif.GBK=alphabetic,chinese-ms936,dingbats,symbol,chinese-ms936-extb
  sequence.sansserif.GBK=alphabetic,chinese-ms936,dingbats,symbol,chinese-ms936-extb
***************
*** 219,224 ****
--- 220,226 ----

  sequence.allfonts.UTF-8.hi=alphabetic/1252,devanagari,dingbats,symbol
  sequence.allfonts.UTF-8.ja=alphabetic,japanese,devanagari,dingbats,symbol
+ sequence.allfonts.UTF-8.ta=alphabetic/1252,tamil,dingbats,symbol

  sequence.allfonts.windows-1255=hebrew,alphabetic/1252,dingbats,symbol

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because its a character encoding problem. Netbeans like IDE would be using the default OS encoding and hence it will print boxes or other funcky characters.

The possible solution is to set your Character encoding to **UTF-8**

> open the project pane if you don't see it already (Window > Projects)
>   Right-click on the name of your project in the tree-view click
>   properties make sure the menu item "sources" on the left is
>   highlighted you should see "Encoding:" and a select-box next to it.
>   click ok.

done.